# how to add more than 1 instance IDs under lambda function python 3.X

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

Please Help i want to add more instance under instance_id.I have Two more instance where i want to run the commands.Instance ID like i-0e946552448dgsd , i-0e946258789itrs.How to add both the IDs under **instance_id** So that the command can be run on both the instances as well.

here is my Lambda function.

```
import time
import json
import boto3


def lambda_handler(event, context):

    # boto3 client
    client = boto3.client("ec2")
    ssm = boto3.client("ssm")

    instance_id = 'i-0e94623888f942c48'
    response = ssm.send_command(
            InstanceIds=[instance_id],
            DocumentName="AWS-RunShellScript",
            Parameters={
                "commands": ["sh /root/test.sh"]
            },  
        )

        # fetching command id for the output
    command_id = response["Command"]["CommandId"]

    time.sleep(3)

        # fetching command output
    output = ssm.get_command_invocation(CommandId=command_id, InstanceId=instance_id)
    print(output)

    return {"statusCode": 200, "body": json.dumps("Thanks!")}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your instance_ids as a list and specify it directly. Also handle fetching command invocation from each instance.

```py
import time
import json
import boto3


def lambda_handler(event, context):

    # boto3 client
    client = boto3.client("ec2")
    ssm = boto3.client("ssm")

    instance_ids = ['i-0e94623888f942c48', 'second_instance_id'] 
    response = ssm.send_command(
            InstanceIds=instance_ids,
            DocumentName="AWS-RunShellScript",
            Parameters={
                "commands": ["sh /root/test.sh"]
            },  
        )

        # fetching command id for the output
    command_id = response["Command"]["CommandId"]

    time.sleep(3)

        # fetching command output
    for instance_id in instance_ids:
        output = ssm.get_command_invocation(CommandId=command_id, InstanceId=instance_id)
        print(output)

    return {"statusCode": 200, "body": json.dumps("Thanks!")}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `InstanceIds` is a *list*. You can provide multiple IDs, for example:

```py
    response = ssm.send_command(
            InstanceIds=['i-0e946552448dgsd', 'i-0e946258789itrs'],
            DocumentName="AWS-RunShellScript",
            Parameters={
                "commands": ["sh /root/test.sh"]
            },  
        )
```